# Simplify the trig function $\frac{2\cos{2x}}{\sin{2x}}$

Tags: trigonometry

How would I simplify the trig function $\frac{2\cos{2x}}{\sin{2x}}$?  Is this a trig identity of can I simplify it down further?

Comment: Is there a universal convention for simplicity that I am unaware of?

Comment: @user63342 : you can write it as $2\cot 2x$, which might be considered simpler.  The answers involve $\cot$ and $\tan$, which some consider less "simple" than $\cos$ and $\sin$, so it is debatable which expression (including the one you gave) is "simplest".

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{2\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)}=\frac{2(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)}{2\sin x\cos x}=\cot x-\tan x$$

Comment: Hello, Sami! Wishing you a wonderful day/evening !

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2\cos{2x}}{\sin{2x}}=\frac{\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}}{\sin{x}\cos{x}}=\cot{x}-\tan{x}$$